# Sum and Join Two tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables: Base table and Detail table. I need to get the count from the Detail table with Base table.

### Tables structure

Base table

```
Nid  UserId  BaseVal
--------------------
1    150     100
```

Detail table

```
Did  Nid  SeqVal
----------------
1    1    500
2    1    600
```

I want this:

Result Table

```
BaseVal  SeqVal
---------------
100      1100
```

I have tried this query but I can get only the Summation value. I need BaseVal too.

```
SELECT SUM(SeqVal) as SEQVAL
FROM TBL_DETAIL
WHERE Nid =: Nid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple answers possible. Assuming your base table always has 1 record and detail table has multiple rows per base table record, a possible answer can be

```
SELECT 
    AVG(BaseVal) Sum_BaseVal, SUM(SeqVal) Sum_SeqVal 
From BaseTable T1, DetailTable T2 
WHERE T1.Nid = T2.Nid 
      AND T1.Nid = :1
```

Bind T1.Nid with right value to ensure you get values for required Nid.

Note: You can also use above query with a `GROUP BY Nid` (it may be necessary if your problem statement is simplified version of a complex query)

Other possible answers can be (I'm giving only 1 to save time, but more exists)

```
WITH 
    SeqSum as (SELECT SUM(SeqVal) Sum_SeqVal FROM DetailTable WHERE Nid = 1)
SELECT BaseVal, Sum_SeqVal 
FROM BaseTable , SeqSum 
WHERE Nid = 1
```

You can further tune queries to have proper conditions if any..

Answer (score 2):

You have to `join` tables first and then calculate the sum:

```
select b.nid, b.baseVal, sum(d.seqVal)
from base_table b join detail_table d on b.nid = d.nid
where b.nid =: Nid
group by b.nid, b.baseVal
```